# Howto read Excel file in Scala

Tags: excel, scala

Is there a way to read an Excel file in Scala (xls not csv)? I mean are there any Scala libraries to do so?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), it's a Java library for reading most of Microsoft's document formats.

Comment: thanks, I thought there are some Scala implementations. This is OK I will go with it.

Comment: For something as complex as reading Excel docs I doubt anyone has thought it worth the effort, not with something like Apache POI available.

Comment: @albert: Most Java libraries work great in Scala out of the box. The ones that don't work so great, you can usually write some wrappers and implicit conversion to make them easily conform to reasonable Scala conventions.

Comment: I've built a set of wrapper Scala classes around POI.  Many goodies, including a very lightweight DSL for building new Excel spreadsheets.  Not yet ready for public consumption, but soon.

Comment: Dave, is that DSL available somewhere?

Comment: there is a DSL here: https://github.com/folone/poi.scala